# Angular Translate | Static Loader | Hide until message.json ajax is complete

Tags: json, angularjs, localization, file-handling, angular-translate

I am using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and its extension [angular-translate-loader-static-files](https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files) to i18 my angular app. Both the required JS files are included in the index.html.

Everything works as expected except that the screen shows the raw message code for a second before we can see the translated messages. I think that happens because the enUS.json (the message translation json) is fetched using an ajax call and until its completed, raw message codes get displayed.

Is there any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not specific to angular-translate.

Either use

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

or

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind